# Speeding up data.frame operations instead of looping

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I have the following dataset in `R`

```
dat <- data.frame(t = rep(seq(1, 5, 1),4), id = rep(c(rep("A",5), rep("B",5), rep("C",5), rep("D",5)), 1),
                  x = 1:20, y = 51:70, h = c(rep(1,10), rep(0,10) ) ) 
require(dplyr)
dat <- arrange(dat, t)
```

The dataset is a panel with `t` as the time variable and `id` as the subject id. I need to attach an additional row, where I compute the sum of `x` times `y` for the remaining subjects at time `t` and divide it by the standard deviation of the `x` variables for the remaining subjects at time `t`. This new row should show a zero for the subjects with `h == 0`.

For example, for subject `A` at time `t == 1`, the operation is: `(6 * 56 + 11 * 61 + 16 * 66) / sd(c(6, 11, 16))`. A similar operation for subject `B` at time `t == 1` is `(1 * 51 + 11 * 61 + 16 * 66) / sd(c(1, 11, 16))`. However, for subjects `C` and `D`, the new row would feature only a 0.

What is the fastest way to do this without a loop? I believe the `dplyr` package is the fastest, but I'm quite new to it, and I'm unsure on how to deal with it. In my attempt I first group by time, and then gather the variables but I receive a warning and several variables are dropped. I'm unsure on how to select the variables for each group.

```
dat %>%
  group_by(t) %>%
  gather(key, value, -t)
# Warning message:
# attributes are not identical across measure variables;
# they will be dropped
```

CONDITIONING

How to include in the previous operation a condition such that in the following table, the operation is computed only when `cond == id`. For example, for the first row we would have: 0 because subjects `B`, `C` and `D` all have values different from their `id` (`cond` is `A`). For row 6 instead the operation is `(2*52 + 12*62 + 17*67) / sd(c(2,12,17))`.

```
dat <- data.frame(t = rep(seq(1, 5, 1),4), id = rep(c(rep("A",5), rep("B",5), rep("C",5), rep("D",5)), 1),
                  x = 1:20, y = 51:70, h = c(rep(1,10), rep(0,10) ) )
dat <- arrange(dat, t)
dat <- data.frame(dat, cond = c("B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "D", "C", "A", "D", "C", "A", "A", "C", "C", "B") )
dat

#    t  id x y  h   cond
# 1  1  A  1 51 1    B
# 2  1  B  6 56 1    A
# 3  1  C 11 61 0    A
# 4  1  D 16 66 0    A
# 5  2  A  2 52 1    A
# 6  2  B  7 57 1    B
# 7  2  C 12 62 0    C
# 8  2  D 17 67 0    D
# 9  3  A  3 53 1    A
# 10 3  B  8 58 1    B
# 11 3  C 13 63 0    D
# 12 3  D 18 68 0    C
# 13 4  A  4 54 1    A
# 14 4  B  9 59 1    D
# 15 4  C 14 64 0    C
# 16 4  D 19 69 0    A
# 17 5  A  5 55 1    A
# 18 5  B 10 60 1    C
# 19 5  C 15 65 0    C
# 20 5  D 20 70 0    B
```

A proposed solution

```
dat %>% 
 filter(id == cond) %>% 
 group_by(t) %>% 
 mutate(new = h * ((sum(x *y) - (x * y))/map_dbl(row_number(), ~ sd(x[-.x])))) %>% 
 bind_rows(dat %>% filter(id != cond))
```

works very well but partially, as it creates `NaN` from multiplying `0 * Inf`. Instead I would like to have `0` when the conditions do not apply or when the standard deviation at the denominator is `0`. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After grouping by 't', create the 'new' column by taking the difference of the `sum` of the products of 'x' and 'y' with the product 'x' and 'y' (to exclude the current row product) and dividing it by getting the `sd` of elements of 'x' by looping through the row index (`row_number()`) to be used for excluding current row and multiply by 'h' so that we get 0 where 'h' is 0.

```
library(tidyverse)
out <- dat %>% 
         group_by(t) %>% 
         mutate(new =  h * ((sum(x *y) - (x * y))/map_dbl(row_number(),
                                                     ~ sd(x[-.x]))))
head(out, 4)
# A tibble: 4 x 6
# Groups:   t [1]
#      t id        x     y     h   new
#  <dbl> <fct> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1 A         1    51     1  413.
#2     1 B         6    56     1  233.
#3     1 C        11    61     0    0 
#4     1 D        16    66     0    0
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you! Would you also know how to extend the code so that I consider in the summation at the numerator and in the sd at the denominator only the individuals that meet a condition? e.g., assume the data is `dat <- data.frame(t = rep(seq(1, 5, 1),4), id = rep(c(rep("A",5), rep("B",5), rep("C",5), rep("D",5)), 1), x = 1:20, y = 51:70, h = c(rep(1,10), rep(0,10) ), cond = sample(c("A", "B"), 20, replace = T) )` and I get `new` only out of the subjects that meet `id != cond`.

Comment: Sorry, if it was confusing. I'm wondering how to modify the `mutate` line with additional conditioning. For example, computing the operation above (sum of remaining subjects / standard deviation) using only data for subjects such that `id == cond` (given that `cond` takes values either in `A` or `B`).

Comment: @Andrew  May be you meant `dat %>% filter(id == cond) %>%  group_by(t) %>% 
         mutate(new =  h * ((sum(x *y) - (x * y))/map_dbl(row_number(),
                                                     ~ sd(x[-.x])))) %>% bind_rows(dat %>% filter(id != cond))`

Comment: Yes! this almost does it! it just creates NaNs instead of zeros. I added an example in the text! Thank you so much Akrun!

Comment: I think adding this two lines to your last code does the trick: `replace_na(list(new = 0)) %>% arrange(t, id)`. Thank you so much!